# Glob pattern to include all files in 'src/main/resources' into GraalVM binary

Tags: java, json, gradle, resources, graalvm

I have a Java project using Gradle to build. The folder structure is as below:

```
<project name>
|- app
   |- bin/
   |- build/
   |- src/
   |  |- main/
   |     |- java
   |     |  |- <package path>
   |     |- resources/
   |        |- <.json files>
   |- build.gradle
```

In my `app/build.gradle` file, I use the Gradle plugin `org.graalvm.buildtools.native` to build a binary file using GraalVM:

```gradle
plugins {
  id 'application'
  id 'org.graalvm.buildtools.native' version '0.9.4'
}

nativeBuild {
  imageName = <image name>
  mainClass = "<package path>.App"
  verbose = true
  fallback = false
  buildArgs.add('-H:IncludeResources=".*\\.json$"')
}
```

The plugin supports adding extra build arguments to GraalVM. So I use `-H:IncludeResources` to try to include all JSON files located in `src/main/resources/`.
When building using the command `./gradlew nativeBuild`, the build process finished successfully. But when running, the `getResourceAsStream` function returns `null` which means it couldn't find those JSON files.

My code to load file content:

```java
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

private String loadTextResourcesFile(String filePath) {
  try {
    String fileText = IOUtils.toString(getClass().getClassLoader()
        .getResourceAsStream(filePath), "UTF-8");
    return fileText;
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
  }
}
```

```java
String fileContent = loadTextResourcesFile("a.json");
```

I think the problem is at `buildArgs.add('-H:IncludeResources=".*\\.json$"')`. Maybe the pattern I used `.*\\.json$` doesn't point to my `app/src/main/resources/*.json` files. But I couldn't find a correct pattern works for my case. Could you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the `nativeBuild` section in `build.gradle` and then add the following:

```gradle
graalvmNative {
  binaries.all {
    resources.autodetect()
  }
  toolchainDetection = false
}
```

This command helps to generate binary file:

```shell
./gradlew nativeCompile --warning-mode all
```

And the plugin also generates the `resource-config.json` file used for `native-image`. You can find the list of resources included:

```shell
cat app/build/native/generated/generateResourcesConfigFile/resource-config.json
```

Reference: https://www.graalvm.org/22.2/reference-manual/native-image/guides/use-native-image-gradle-plugin/#build-a-native-executable-with-resources-autodetection

If you're using [Picocli](https://picocli.info/) you may also need this in the `build.gradle` file:

```gradle
compileJava {
  options.compilerArgs += [
    "-Aproject=${project.group}/${project.name}",
    "-Aother.resource.patterns=.*"
  ]
}
```

(`.*` will include all files under `src/main/resources` that you want to embed into the binary. For more details about `other.resource.patterns`, please refer to https://github.com/remkop/picocli/tree/main/picocli-codegen#222-other-options)

Comment: Thanks for the note on PicoCLI; that exactly where all my earlier attempts failed!